# Enable location dialog is not opening properly

Tags: android

Once app launched I am trying to open enable location dialog. Dialog is only opened but enable location option is not showing in dialog, only blank white dialog is showing. I am attaching screenshot with this post [image] can you guys help me with this?

Code

```
package abc.xyz;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
        boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(!statusOfGPS)
        {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }
   }

    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.gps_disabled)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle(R.string.gps_disabled_title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.enable,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(
                @SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog,
                @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(
        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
    })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
        @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


}
```

Comment: this idea is deprecated, new is open request permission dialog once user enable location permission GPS Location will  automatically on.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar can you help me with code?

Comment: sure, follow the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  private void buildAlertMessageNoGps(Context context)
    {
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    googleApiClient.connect();

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000 / 2);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to upgrade location settings ");

                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                        // in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(LoginScreen.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog not created.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Getting errors, can you help? `Error:(16) error: resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka abc.xyz:integer/google_play_services_version) not found.
Error:(16) resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka abc.xyz:integer/google_play_services_version) not found.
Error:failed processing manifest.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:`

Comment: add this library build.gradle

 `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'`
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0'`

add permission in Manifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: More errors `Error:(29, 9) error: cannot find symbol class GoogleApiClient
Error:(30, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable LocationServices
Error:(29, 62) error: package GoogleApiClient does not exist
Error:(33, 9) error: cannot find symbol class LocationRequest
Error:(33, 43) error: cannot find symbol variable LocationRequest
Error:(34, 37) error: cannot find symbol variable LocationRequest
Error:(38, 32) error: package LocationSettingsRequest does not exist
Error:(38, 78) error: package LocationSettingsRequest does not exist`

Comment: More errors `Error:(23, 8) error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method onConnectionSuspended(int) in ConnectionCallbacks
Error:(72, 80) error: cannot find symbol variable REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
`

Comment: Only few errors, Please help? `Error:(71, 80) error: cannot find symbol variable REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

`

Comment: please `implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener` in your MainActivity class and override all methods

Comment: All errors have been solved now but app is not opening up, it's always getting stopped

Comment: What do you mean stop. check your logcat

Comment: Here it is `com.abc.gpslauncher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.abc.gpslauncher, PID: 3779
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.gpslauncher/com.abc.gpslauncher.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.abc.gpslauncher.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated`